# Why my multiparted .tar unpacs just partly? (missing files)

Tags: windows, linux, tar, 7-zip, gzip

I have 25 .tar files like: `filename.tar.001` - `filename.tar.025`

When I want to unpack them with `cat myarchive.tar.* | tar xvf -` it does, but missing files: whole .tar is 1,2 GB, but unpacked files have just 600MB - I have ~200 files missing out of ~400.

Ive tared them using 7zip on my Windows OS: `add to archive > .tar > 50 MB per part`

Little image what I mean: [image]

Comment: It may be the splitting function of 7zip or the tar of 7zip, have you tried w/o splitting the file. Another option would be to try with the real [tar](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gtar.htm)

Comment: Why would you be trying to cat the files together?  Shouldn't you be using the `--multi-volume` option?

Comment: Have you checked to see the missing files are present in the tar archive, and not extracting, or aren't present and so didn't make it into the tar in the first place?

Comment: @Zoredache Its packed, on my local machine it unpacks OK with 7zip. And whats about --multi-volume?

Comment: @ 0xAF I do not speak your language, cant understand you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no official specification for a multi-part tarball. Use `cat` on the server to combine them first.

```
cat ...tar.* > ....tar
tar zxf ....tar
```

Comment: `$ cat Main.tar.* > Main.tar
$ tar zxf Main.tar`
returns:
`gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now`